# Personalization with Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, personalization

Can anybody provide any pointers to good books or use cases about personalization (especially with Hadoop)? Are there any good web resources about this topic?

Comment: What do you mean by `Personalization`? Changing a logo or the background color of the web UI? Or `Recommendation Engines`?

Answer (score 0):

The closest things to personalization and hadoop (or big data in general) are applications in which a set of products is recommended to users based on their specific transaction history with the company and on observed patterns across all users.  One example to look at would be how Netflix uses hadoop.

This differs slightly from the traditional meaning of personalization, which has to do with content delivery based on a user's role, status or group membership.

Comment: It's not clear to me how personalization doesn't include user history and data from other users--personalization includes using any data that's available in order to make *personalized* recommendations.